# How to use dplyr's rowwise() in pipe in R to apply a function that returns a list to each row?

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe, rowwise

I would like to use dplyr's rowwise() and the pipe to apply a function (that returns a list) to each row in the dataframe.

Test dataset with two rows:

```
test_tbl <- tibble(a=c(2, 4), b=c(0, 8), c=c(5, -3))
```

Defining a simple function (it's about a function returning a list, obviously not about adding 8):

```
simple_function <- function(input) {
  list(input + 8)
}
```

This is what I would like to achieve:

```
apply(test_tbl ,1, function (x) simple_function(x))
```

which returns a list of 2 lists (my desired output).

I would like to save those lists as a column in the tibble. We could do:

```
test_tbl %>% mutate(output = apply(. ,1, function (x) simple_function(x)))
```

I'd rather use dplyr than mixing up dplyr, base, and the pipe (also for readability of code), but I do not understand why this doesn't work:

```
test_tbl %>% rowwise() %>% simple_function
test_tbl %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(output = simple_function(.))
```

Both of these functions apply the function to the entire dataframe rather than to the seperate rows. It makes no sense to me that:
`test_tbl %>% rowwise() %>% simple_function` is identical (in terms of output) to `test_tbl %>% simple_function`

This does give the desired output, but I find it rather verbose and not ideal that I have to bind the columns myself:

```
test_tbl %>% rowwise() %>% do(output= simple_function(.)) %>% bind_cols(test_tbl, .)
```

Any help on why `rowwise()` is failing is much appreciated.

Comment: We need `test_tbl %>% mutate_all(funs(. + 8))`.  It is not clear why the output should be a `list`.  If that is not the case, just add within `mutate_all`

Comment: The simple function is an example; the function that I would like to apply is something more complicated (which generates some dataframe on the basis of the values of the column).  The crucial bit is that a list-column should be formed, with a list created for each row.

Answer (score 2):

If we need to do this on each row, then `split` and apply the function within `map`

```
library(tidyverse)
test_tbl %>% 
    split(., seq_len(nrow(.))) %>%
    map(simple_function)
#$`1`
#$`1`[[1]]
#   a b  c
#1 10 8 13


#$`2`
#$`2`[[1]]
#   a  b c
#1 12 16 5
```